# Set behavior for interpreting text field input for date in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am running Rails 3.1.1 and trying to properly interpret dates entered by the user in a text input. Since this is a US-based app, I want users to be able to enter a %m/%d/%y date.

For example, if a user enters in "1/4/2010" in a birth_date field, I would want that to be written to the DB as January 4, 2010.

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237890/change-format-for-date-input-in-rails-3) that seems to cover it, but it seems complicated. There must be cleaner way.

I tried overriding the getter method in my model, to no avail:

```
def birth_date=(date)
  @birth_date = Time.strptime(date,"%m/%d/%y").to_date
end
```

I had also changed my environment.rb to include:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But that does not seem to handle the inbound interpretation, only the outbound formatting.

It would seem crazy to me that this fairly key CRUD feature isn't covered in Rails. (Usually in this situation, it is because I am missing something.)

Comment: Are you using a :datetime or :date field or asking users to manually type in the value into a :text_field?

Comment: I am using a form helper text input for user input `<%= f.text_field :birth_date, :value => date_format(f.object.birth_date) %>` and a date field in the database `t.date "birth_date"`